# L3 switch - All L3 processing offloaded to card?

Tags: switch, layer3

On a Cisco 3560 switch, are all L3 processing offloaded to card instead of normal CPU?

Comment: Do you have specific hardware in mind? Because you could design a L3 switch however you want, with or without what is commonly considered a CPU.

Comment: @KillianDS Cisco 3550, 3560. From packet processing perspective, does the card process it the same as CPU (machine with L3 process is on CPU, not card)?

Comment: I don't understand what card you're talking about; both the 3550 and 3560 are 1RU systems

Comment: @MikePennington Isn't packet is processed on ASIC instead of normal CPU in those switches? This is my 1st time hear term 1RU system. I read about it but couldn't find how it is related to L3 switching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the 3560 switch, as well as on most modern L3 switches still being sold, L3 is done on ASIC that handles a number of things - including L2 switching, L3 routing, ACLs, QoS and so on. "Normal CPU" is being used for chassis management and interaction with the user/admin.

There's no separate "card" in 1RU/2RU systems usually. On the chassis systems yes, sometimes L3 processing is done on a separate daughterboard on the line cards (in distributed fashion) or in main management module (usually called Supervisor).